# Ассемблер: системные вызовы

Tags: ассемблер, архитектура

Изучаю ассемблер, остановился на системных вызовах.
Архитектура х86, операционка линукс.

К примеру, если взять системный вызов `sys_socketcall`. И используя его, хочу, к примеру, посмотреть, что прилетает ко мне на любой интернет-сокет.

```
mov eax,102;   номер системного вызова, далее идут параметры
mov ebx,.....; проблема именно в этом я не знаю какие параметры передавать  
...........
...........
int 80h
```

Comment: Полистайте вот это [книжку](http://www.stolyarov.info/books/asm_unix)

Comment: Не  знаю, как книжка, а автор, судя по переписке на страничке -- нормальный.

Comment: @avp, книжка очень хорошая. Правда, читал давно.

Comment: Поздравляю! (я даже не сомневаюсь что успешно).

Теперь кандидат (или доктор???) и новая должность, новые заботы?

Comment: прочел всю,
там есть пару примеров по системным вызовам, и на этом примеры закончились

Comment: Кандидат. Биологических. Но еще должны утвердить и все такое

Comment: но все равно спасибо